# Laravel 5: Decryption error The Mac is invalid

Tags: laravel, encryption

When i try to login the following error produced:

```
DecryptException in BaseEncrypter.php line 49:
The MAC is invalid.
```

I am using xampp with php 7.

The laravel version that i use is 5.2.

*I have change the api key running `php artisan key:generate`.
**I have trying the following commands: `php artisan cache:clear` `composer dump-autoload` `composer update` with no lucky.
I have clear the history of the browser.

** Here are the values of some variables:

```
iv=a69g/gRfyCNWTaKeuZ2Kkw==
value=C7DfTHbFWfZq0km633uXMX0ZRd1fuzcFFBgP0vtZj/d4C4Z3btgeFlmU2a1C9TdUlUDof4mnoGhdvEeB/gL1TQ==
mac=c0460e4ea3d724631cf4a12b7b19a5e512ecec8f492b4754e183714cc9d0a05c
```

Any help would be usefull.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: solved in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070732/laravel-decryptexception-the-mac-is-invalid/47926508#47926508](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070732/laravel-decryptexception-the-mac-is-invalid/47926508#47926508)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an error on redis server.
Hope that someone will help.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a little late but it might be useful for future me or someone else.

I had an issue where I had to encrypt something in the database, changed the **APP_KEY** and then tried to decrypt it and this error happened.

Comment: It can also apply when a CSRF token is provided as POST data that does not decrypt correctly based on the current APP_KEY, ie: it's forged

Answer (score 0):

There might be some issue with the `.env` file as I am having the same problem.

There should be space between `APP_KEY` and `APP_DEBUG`

Answer (score 0):

I could find a solution I tried everything including regenerating. However, this worked for me... If you have an existing app_key (in another folder/locally)  you may want to restore, you can update it in the .env file manually. Locate the APP_KEY entry in the file and replace the value with the key in your initial .env in your previous project