# DecryptException in BaseEncrypter.php line 48: The MAC is invalid while change admin password

Tags: laravel, exception, password-encryption

I am new to laravel and i have my project in local as well in server. i can change password in local. But i cant in server. When i try to change admin password i the the following error in console

```
>  in BaseEncrypter.php line 48 at
> BaseEncrypter->getJsonPayload('eyJpdiI6Ik03S3lnNkRFeUNwMkpmb1BDeFY5ZGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZWxIVDg5XC8xXC9pU1hNUkFTNGpSUmZnPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI5NDkxOGYzNTM5YzgxY2NkZTZjZTY2MTBlYWE2NmJlN2M5YjVhMjc0NmQ0ZDUwMzUyYTYzZDhjNWZjZDIzYmZkIn0=')
> in Encrypter.php line 96 at
> Encrypter->decrypt('eyJpdiI6Ik03S3lnNkRFeUNwMkpmb1BDeFY5ZGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZWxIVDg5XC8xXC9pU1hNUkFTNGpSUmZnPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI5NDkxOGYzNTM5YzgxY2NkZTZjZTY2MTBlYWE2NmJlN2M5YjVhMjc0NmQ0ZDUwMzUyYTYzZDhjNWZjZDIzYmZkIn0=')
> in Facade.php line 218
```

i checked App_key in .env file.

can anyone help me..Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to clear the laravel cache and composer dump-autoload?

Comment: Try clearing cache and clearing cookie of browser.  Also try to remove cache files

Comment: yes i tried cleared cache..but not fixed..thanks for your response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5: Decryption error The Mac is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327565/laravel-5-decryption-error-the-mac-is-invalid)