# Can't using Visual Code to debug in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, visual-studio-code

I was config success to debug in PHP on VSCode.

My problem is when I run the project it always errors at the function:

```
protected function getJsonPayload($payload)
{
    $payload = json_decode(base64_decode($payload), true);

    // If the payload is not valid JSON or does not have the proper keys set we will
    // assume it is invalid and bail out of the routine since we will not be able
    // to decrypt the given value. We'll also check the MAC for this encryption.
    if (! $this->validPayload($payload)) {
        throw new DecryptException('The payload is invalid.');
    }

    if (! $this->validMac($payload)) {
        throw new DecryptException('The MAC is invalid.');
    }

    return $payload;
}
```

... from file: `/srv/http/laravelproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php`

I can't debug to breakpoint I was set.

Gif screen record: [http://i.imgur.com/6pNkoHe.gif](https://i.imgur.com/6pNkoHe.gif)

Comment: Where do you debug? Docker? Vagrant? Want?

Comment: @TzookBarNoy I debug a function on my controller in Laravel project. I don't use Docket or Vagrant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question seems to be a related post to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960999/how-to-run-or-debug-php-on-visual-studio-code-vscode?rq=1), which provides a pretty good answer. Also, my question to you is why are you using `DecryptException`? Laravel has `bcrypt`(for password hashing) and `csrf tokens` (form data encryption) that are much easier to use.

For those looking for a quick answer without reading the comments:

Run **these** commands in Eloquent:

`php artisan optimize` -> `php artisan cache:clear` -> `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: You can see this gif.http://i.imgur.com/6pNkoHe.gif. I don't use `DecryptException`. I think my error relationship with cookies when login. Your link provides only for setup debug. I know how to debug in VSCode and setup success.

Comment: Your image doesn't load - comes up as `404`.

Comment: This might be a longshot, but hear me out. I had issues using the `Voyager` package before. First, try running `php artisan optimize` and see what happens. And then clear cache and cookies in the testing browser.

Comment: So, the exception is thrown within VSCode and not when browsing the site? I find that weird.

Comment: See if [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327565/laravel-5-decryption-error-the-mac-is-invalid) helps as well. It mentions that it might be a server/redis issue.

Comment: thanks for your link. seem all my effort with your help can't resolve.

Comment: hey. I try with: `php artisan optimize`. -> `php artisan cache:clear` -> `composer dump-autoload`. Clear all cache and cookies on my browser. It's working. Thanks @robertdewitt.

Comment: Anytime!! Wow, I almost didn't think that would work. But yeah, when in doubt, use `optimize`. It solves **A LOT** of issues.

Answer (score 16):

Had the same issue when using Docker with VsCode and xDebug in Laravel.

For anyone interested in a different approach (since Laravel 5.6 there is no `optimize` command anymore)

Just add the `ignore` section to your `launch.json` config.

```
{
   "name": "Listen for XDebug",
   "type": "php",
   "request": "launch",
   "port": 9000,
   "pathMappings": {
       "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}",
    },
    // add this
    "ignore": [
        "**/vendor/**/*.php"
    ]
},
```

Solved the issue for me.

Got this from [Docker Github Repo](https://github.com/petronetto/php7-alpine#vs-code)

Comment: Perfecto. Thank you!

Comment: Dear God this took me hours to find.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and the accepted answer solved it.

However, if anyone simply wants to dismiss the problem temporarily, rather than getting to the root of it, you can uncheck the "Everything" checkbox at the bottom of the Breakpoints panel of the debug pane, and that will skip over the error.

Comment: This also a tips useful. Voted.

Comment: This was the only thing that helped me, considering the limitations on my project. Thank you, I'm up and running!

Answer (score 1):

On Laravel 5.7, it works for me:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,
        "ignore": [
            "**/vendor/**/*.php"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9000,
        "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/php"
    }
]
}
```