# The payload is invalid

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, xdebug, laravel-5.5

I am new to Laravel. When I am in debug mode I get the following errors every time every page loads:

> The payload is invalid

After pressing two times on Continue I get the error

> The MAC is invalid

The error messages are located inside the `encrypter.php` file. After pressing "Continue" again, I can proceed with debugging with breakpoints and so on, and everything works fine. The `$payload-variable` is null.

The project is still very basic. Only some things like CRUD like explained on tutorials.

What is payload? And am I missing some kind of configuration? How to get rid of these error messages?

[image: Screenshot Error message]

Comment: This seems like a problem with your IDE or browser. Which ones are you using? Can you post a screenshot of the error?

Comment: I did. It is at the end of my post.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome and Visual Studio Code

Comment: Have you run `php artisan key:generate` yet?

Comment: I did not run key:generate, but the APP_KEY constant is present in my.env file. Should I run it?

Comment: The app_key has to be a specific length etc. Did you create your own?

Comment: I did not create my own. I expect it has been there since I created the project

Comment: Anyone? I would like to get this solved.

Comment: Just try to run `php artisan key:generate` and see if that solves it.

Comment: I did run php artisan key:generate. I got a new key, but the problem is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is found in this post:

[Can't using Visual Code to debug in Laravel project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669744/cant-using-visual-code-to-debug-in-laravel-project#)

I also:

1. closed VS Code Editor
2. cleared all history in my browser, including cookies and cache
3. ran the commands as mentioned in the post inside the windows cmd window (so not the integrated terminal inside VS Code Editor)